# TidMessage exception handling not working for EConvertError

Tags: delphi, indy

I am trying to read and handle an email file created by Thunderebird.  I am using `TIdMessage`.  It works fine for the vast majority of emails, except for those with date problems.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  CRLF = #13#10;
var
  IndyStringList: TStringList;
  IndyStream: TMemoryStream;
  IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
begin                      
  IdMessage1 := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  s1 := 'C:\Temp\MboxTest4.txt'; //  shortened problem file

  IndyStringList := TStringList.Create;
  IndyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  IndyStringList.LoadFromFile(s1);
  IndyStringList.Add(CRLF + '.' + CRLF);
  IndyStringList.SaveToStream(IndyStream);
  IndyStream.Position := 0;
  try
    IdMessage1.LoadFromStream(IndyStream);
  except
    on E: EConvertError do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName + '  ' + E.Message);
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

When I run this with a file that contains a bad `Date`, the `EConvertError` and `Exception` handlers are not executed, and the program proceeds as though there was no error.

Here is the email:

```
From - Mon Jan 1 00:00:00 1965
X-Persona: <support@LondonDatabases>
Received: from yass.news.co.uk [194.129.35.178] by londondatabases.com
  (SMTPD32-6.06) id A3FA150060; Thu, 29 Aug 2002 10:47:22 -0400
From: Sunday Times Enterprise Network <01582485-001069-1644@yass.news.co.uk>
To: support@londondatabases.com
Date: Thu, 29 August 2002 15:40:46 +0100 (BST)
Subject: The Sunday Times Enterprise Network
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252
Content-Disposition: inline
User-Agent: YASS
Message-Id: <200208291047574.SM00940@yass.news.co.uk>
X-RCPT-TO: <support@londondatabases.com>
X-UIDL: 313625295
Status: U
X-Mozilla-Status: 8000
X-Mozilla-Status2: 00000000
Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit


 <HTML>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you expect an exception to be raised. Let's start from the assumption that the library behaves as designed.

Comment: If it is designed on the assumption that all emails are impeccably formatted then we don't need error handling. I am wondering if that is the case? 
Any suggestions as to alternatives to TidMessage if it is designed to fail when the data is not perfect?

Comment: That sort of question is a recommendation question and is off topic here. I think you need to study the code of the Indy library that you are using to determine how it works. I don't think you can expect this to be documented.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am not a good programmer and what you suggest is beyond my capabilities. That is why I am here. :-)

Comment: We aren't here to do your job for you though. Perhaps it's time to improve your skills? Working out what this library does could be the opportunity you need to do just that.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the Indy library is not made for people like me. Perhaps I am a bit naive, but I thought component libraries were designed to help people avoid "looking under the hood"

Comment: Yes and no. In an ideal world, Indy would have excellent and comprehensive documentation. But it doesn't. It's an open source project, a very impressive and extensive one. But one developed by people in their spare time. It's understandable that a project like this isn't heavily documented. If you aren't able to dig into the code, which does indeed require significant expertise, then perhaps you would indeed be better off with a well documented library. I don't know whether or not Indy has a support forum, but if so you could try there. And Remy may well turn up here to help you.

Comment: Thank you. Let's hope Remy takes an interest.

Comment: We cannot see the contents of `C:\Temp\MboxTest4.txt`. So we have no reason to believe it should raise any kind of exception. We have no way to verify or reproduce your problem. If you define your message as `const`, then at least you'll be close to a proper ***complete*** MCVE. Add to that an explanation of ***what in the message*** you believe should trigger an exception, and there'll be lots of people who might be able to answer. Right now you're being disrespectful to Remy others expecting them to do all the leg-work for you.

Comment: "_what you suggest is beyond my capabilities_" I'd like to point out that for everyone here who is capable of answering your question (_provided we have **enough information**_):  There was a point in time where this would have been beyond our capabilities as well. The only way we learned was by getting stuck in with a debugger and learning by reading and stepping through code. If you're not willing to do that, you'll never be able to learn for yourself.

Comment: It's pretty [well documented](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdMessage_LoadFromStream@TIdStream@Boolean.html). See Exceptions section.

Comment: Hmm, have I been maligning the documentation of Indy?

Comment: I have placed the file here:

http://qbusters.com.au/ida/MboxTest4.txt

Comment: @user1355041 Why should people on this site waste their time for your royal benefit? If you show that you care about your own work, you'll get much better help much more quickly. [Edit] your question and set the file data in a **const**. (Make sure your [mcve] is ***complete***.)

Comment: I tried posting data here, but was told it is too many characters. I seem to be upsetting a lot of people. Sorry about that. I am doing my best.

Comment: @user1355041 I don't think you're upsetting many people. But you're not doing what's needed to get the help to solve your problem. If the file is too large, you need to find the smallest file that causes whatever problem you're experiencing. That's the point of ***minimal*** in MCVE.

Comment: Since your file is only 766 bytes, it is not at all too big to post *in your question*. It is though too big to post as a comment. So, use the "edit" button under the tags of your question to add the content of the file.

Comment: Also, the `date` field in that message is `Date: Thu, 29 August 2002 15:40:46 +0100 (BST)`, I don't see why you think that is a bad date.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: because it is malformed, `August` must be `Aug` instead, per RFC 822

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "*I don't know whether or not Indy has a support forum*" - yes. NNTP newsgroups (news.atozed.com) and Web forums (forums2.atozed.com) (which have both been offline for awhile), and a chat room on Gitter (gitter.im/IndySockets/Indy). Alternatively, there is always StackOverflow, and the Internet/Winsock sections on Embarcadero's forums are frequently used for Indy questions, too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan FYI, AtoZed has created a new web forum for CrossTalk, IntraWeb, and Indy: https://www.atozed.com/forums/

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using a `TStringList` to load the email file the way you are (and you shouldn't be using `CRLF` with `TStringList.Add()` anyway).  There is no reason to manually inject a `CRLF+'.'+CRLF` sequence into the email data (unless you are using a very old version of Indy that does not already handle that internally).  You should be using the `TIdMessage.LoadFromFile()` method instead:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
begin                      
  try
    IdMessage1 := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    try
      IdMessage1.LoadFromFile('C:\Temp\MboxTest4.txt');
    finally
      IdMessage1.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Or, the `TIdMessageHelper.LoadFromFile()` method if the email's lines are not escaped in a dot-transparency format (see [New TIdMessage helper](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20150730.aspx) for more details):

```
uses
  ..., IdMessageHelper;

procedure TForm1.ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
begin                      
  try
    IdMessage1 := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    try
      // if using D2006+
      IdMessage1.LoadFromFile('C:\Temp\MboxTest4.txt', False, False);

      // if using pre-D2006
      TIdMessageHelper_LoadFromFile(IdMessage1, 'C:\Temp\MboxTest4.txt', False, False);
    finally
      IdMessage1.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Either way, the reason your code doesn't catch the date conversion error is because Indy catches the exception internally and sets the `TIdMessage.Date` property to `0.0`.  The exception is not raised into your code, so you can only see it if you are running your code inside of the IDE's debugger.

And the reason why the email's `Date` header is failing to parse is because it is malformed per the rules of [RFC 822 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5).  `August` should be `Aug` instead, then it parses correctly:

```
Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2002 15:40:46 +0100 (BST)
```

However, Indy does account for several alternative language spellings that are not allowed by RFC 822, but it wasn't handling full month names.  So I have just now updated Indy to support parsing additional spellings, and now your original "malformed" `Date` will parse without error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out tomorrow as it is very late here. :-)

Comment: I confirm that it works as described. Thank you once more.

If you can post the patch that allows the processing of full month names, I would be most grateful.

Comment: @user1355041 you can generate your own patch from [Indy's SVN server](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.aspx), or just [download](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.aspx) and [install](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx) the latest nightly snapshot.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do that.